# Friendship with non mahram

Tags: practical-islam, muslim-practices, non-mahram, friendship, social-media

Is talking to non mahram friend is jinah?
If we stay in limit by not saying anything adultry
Just chat in social media then is it jinah ? Or haram ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have talk, come in contact or chat with them. It is sinful. It may lead one to do a major sin like zina. It is not permissible to have friends of opposite sex. There will Satanic whispers which might lead to Zina.

Allah says in the Quran,
“Tell the believing men to lower their gaze (from looking at forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts, etc.). That is purer for them. Verily, Allah is All-Aware of what they do“ [24:30]

You have to lower gaze when you see people of opposite sex and don’t have any type chat with them.
Jazakallah Kahiran